# Masonry Isnt working After Javascript Image Load

Tags: javascript, load, masonry

Any help would be appreciated. Im brand spankin new to Masonry's Grid Layout. Im trying to get it to work but no such luck. I feel it's because the images are loading after from the JS.

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
</div>

/** CSS

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

 /* force scrollbar */
html { overflow-y: scroll; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
  background: #DDD;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33.333%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/** JS

$(function() {
    var folder = "imgs/wedding/";

$.ajax({
    url : folder,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(JPG)$/) ) { 
                $(".grid").append( "<div class='grid-item'><img src='"+ folder + val +"'></div>" );
            } 
        });
    }

});


var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  percentPosition: true,
  columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
});
// layout Isotope after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry();
});  
});
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get Masonry to acknowledge the JS loaded images? Thanks!

Comment: if you're doing masonry, why aren't you using css `columns`?

Comment: explain please.

Comment: http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/